# Xlint:unused in Play framework vs. implicits

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, playframework, compiler-warnings, implicit

I'm developing a project in Scala (99%, plus 1% Java) using the Play framework.

I would like to get compile-time warnings or errors about unused names (imports and variables).

However, if I just enable -Xlint:unused (or -Ywarn-unused) I get many spurious errors about implicits which are only used implicitly (but never explicitly by name).

Is there somewhere of configuring -Xlint:unused such that it doesn't flag such variables as unused? I'm using Scala 2.12.10 FWIW.

Comment: I'm not sure about this specific Scala version but I've never experienced that: implicits are properly identified as used or not used.

Comment: Did you have a look to https://tpolecat.github.io/2017/04/25/scalac-flags.html ?